# Refresh DataTable without reloading page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am trying to reload data tables that have been inserted into tabs.

**Please refer to question**: [AJAX Update DataTable after On Success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63939440/ajax-update-datatable-after-on-success?noredirect=1#comment113065267_63939440)

A PHP class userX.php has 3 data tables with client-side implementations. I am able to change a row of the first table using a button, once it is done the record will go to tab 2 -> and the content of it table two. I am changing the status now using AJAX as this:

```
  $(".changeStatus").click(function(event){
      if(confirm("Are you sure changing status?")){
        event.preventDefault();
        var status =  "In Production";
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $.ajax({
          url     : 'dbo.php',
          method  : 'POST',
          data    : {status : status , id : id},
          success : function(data){
            $('tr#'+id+'').css('background-color', '#ccc');
            $('tr#'+id+'').fadeOut('slow');
          }
        });
      }
      else{
        return false;
      }
    });
```

In the meantime it has to be updated in the tab 2 table as well. I have tried achieving this using div contents; neither of them seems working. What am I missing? I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The table can simply be reloaded by reinitializing method of the datatable also reloading it through its built in AJAX. The below code block would help.

```
             $(document).on('click','#ChangeNext',function(event){
                if(confirm("Are you sure changing status?")){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var statusid = $(this).attr('data-id');
                    $.ajax({
                        url     : 'dbo.php',
                        method  : 'POST',
                        data    : {statusid : statusid},
                        success : function(data)
                        {
                            $('#exampleone').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                        }
                    });
                }
                else{
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Mahn!! you saved me after sweating a whole day

Comment: @stephenwaweru99 I knew the pain bro. :)

Answer (score 0):

the best way for putting data in a DataTables with ajax requests, is DataTables ajax api that you can see it in following link:

[DataTables Ajax sourced data](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax)

jQuery sample:

```
jQuery('.changeStatus').click(function(event){
    $('#example').DataTable({ ajax: 'data.json' });
});
```

JSON Sample:

```
{
    "data": [
        [
            "Roshan Zaid",
            "Stackoverflow user",
            "New member"
        ],
        [
            "AmirAli Esteki",
            "Stackoverflow and AskUbuntu user",
            "New member"
        ]
    ]
}
```

the response of your ajax requests should be json by default

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. The main thing is the datatable is not AJAX sourced, it is just the DOM. Therefore, when i request a json, it throws an error. Also, refactoring all tables to ajax source is not possible since I have 3 tables with huge configurations in one page.

Comment: If changing datatables based to Ajax source would be the only solution, then I have to change the whole concept from the beginning of the project. But it's okay I will give it a try then.